# Remove windows 7 entry from grub

Tags: windows-7, grub, ubuntu-10.04

I recently installed ubuntu 10.04 LTS and formatted my windows 7 hdd, but the windows 7 entry is still showing in grub. How can I remove the entry from grub?

Greetz

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GrubHowto

Answer (score 8):

You should edit the `/etc/default/grub` and add the following line:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

save it and perform

```
sudo update-grub .
```

It will remove Windows from your GRUB menu list.

[Hide/remove Windows entry from Grub menu list](http://www.ubuntucafe.in/2012/05/hideremove-windows-entry-from-grub-menu.html)

Answer (score 4):

The problem with these answers is that they do not address the underlying problem - when Windows is installed, it scans all drives on the system and 'litters' qualifying drives with 'Recycle' folders and other Microsoft OS what-nots, that Grub then takes to be an existing M$ OS.

Including the "GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true" line will prevent ALL other operating systems from being detected, including other  Linux OS's.

So the best fix is simply to delete these additional files/folders that Windows has created prior to running  "update-grub".  Window's menu-items will no longer be present in the Grub menu.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.04 LTS uses Grub2, which no longer uses the `/boot/grub/menulist.lst` file for configuration.

Instead, you should edit the file  `/etc/default/grub`.

If your hard disk still contains a Windows partition, add the line:

> GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true

to prevent Windows being added to your grub menu.

To write the change, run

> sudo update-grub

which will write a new `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file.

You can then run

> cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg

to check that your Windows entry has disappeared.

Further information can be found on this page:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Answer (score 1):

If the entry was manually created, all you need to do is remove the corresponding file in `/etc/grub.d/` using the command:

```
sudo rm /etc/grub.d/<filename>
```

Make sure you know what you're doing, you don't want to delete the wrong file as it will cause boot problems.

Also, you might not want to disable `os-prober` if you have a dual- or multi-boot system.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling *os-prober* wasn't correct solution in my case - I had 2 Windows entries and just wanted to remove one incorrect. I was able to achieve desired effect using following Grub configuration:

1.Check UUIDs for the disks using the command:

```
sudo blkid
```

2.Update */etc/default/grub* file by adding the line:

```
GRUB_OS_PROBER_SKIP_LIST="UUID_OF_DISK_YOU_DONT_WANT_SCAN1 UUID_OF_DISK_YOU_DONT_WANT_SCAN2"
```

3.Regenerate Grub configuration:

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

NOTE: *grub2-mkconfig* due to some reasons still displays information about the ignored disk, but it wasn't generated to final */boot/grub2/grub.cfg* file.

I've posted this as an answer for similar question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408464/update-grub-brings-back-manually-removed-menu-entries/466359#466359

Answer (score 0):

If I remember corretly, you need to edit `/boot/grub/menu.lst` on your linux drive and remove the windows 7 entry (it's a text file)

The entry looks something like this:

```
title Windows 7
root (hd1,0)
savedefault
makeactive
map (hd0) (hd1)
map (hd1) (hd0)
chainloader +1
```

Comment: That would be correct for grub 1, but Ubuntu 10.04 uses grub 2, which has a more complicated scheme, generated from files in /etc/grub.d

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to simply run `sudo update-grub` however if you only need to remove a specific windows partition from grub2, everything i tried re-envoked the OS prober, which put the partition right back as an option. disabling the OS prober was not a fit because I did have windows partitions i wanted listed as options. the only solution i found was to edit the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file manually, using `#` to comment out the entirety of the entry for the undesired partition. note that any other updates to `grub.cfg` will require re-commenting-out the undesired partition.